# java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation

Tags: android

package com.fio.gmapsactivity;

**GMapsActivity**

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
    public class GMapsActivity extends MapActivity {
private MapView mapView;
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map_view);       
mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
}
@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}
}
```

**activity_map.xml**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:apiKey="AIzaSyB4sGJQVW1hJpOtWnTHvDw5IxV_YOPA9eA"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:enabled="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Mainfest.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.fio.gmapsactivity"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
    android:name="com.fio.gmapsactivity.GMapsActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyB4sGJQVW1hJpOtWnTHvDw5IxV_YOPA9eA" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    </manifest>
```

I have add jar files(effects,maps,usb).but can't able to map.only showing error.can't able to find the error.please help me.

**Error**

```
    02-25 02:49:31.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1812): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    02-25 02:49:31.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1812): java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-     verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
    02-25 02:49:31.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1812): at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(Native Method)
    02-25 02:49:31.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1812): at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:211)
    02-25 02:49:31.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1812): at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:313)
    02-25 02:49:31.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1812): at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:51)
    02-25 02:49:31.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1812): at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
    02-25 02:49:31.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1812): at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
    02-25 02:49:31.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1812): at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
    02-25 02:49:31.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1812): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
    02-25 02:49:31.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1812): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
    02-25 02:49:31.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1812): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    02-25 02:49:31.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1812): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
    02-25 02:49:31.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1812): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    02-25 02:49:31.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1812): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    02-25 02:49:31.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1812): at   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
    02-25 02:49:31.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1812): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    02-25 02:49:31.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1812): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    02-25 02:49:31.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1812): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
    02-25 02:49:31.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1812): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    02-25 02:49:31.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1812): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this myself. When your class was compiled into the classes.dex file a dependent class had a certain spec. When the classes.dex file was loaded up during app or test execution the dependent class looked different. Often times this is a result of double including a library in your project (and they're different). Since you mention you added jar files you might remove all of them and re-add them as the errors present themselves. I would suggest completely cleaning your project between runs as the build system may not recompile your classes.dex file if you aren't changing your source files between builds. For the same reason you might be able to build successfully sometimes while other times you build and get an apk that causes this error.

Also, I can see you're using Google Play Services. You'll want to make sure you're only including that dependencies via the library project (Eclipse only) or the dependencies directive (Gradle). If you included a jar manually for Google Play Services it would cause this issue as well.